# ByteArray pass across JS and AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript, arrays

i have sound data as ByteArray in AS3. need that to be transferred to javascript, which is later send back to AS3 for play back.

i tried converting it to string by readUTFBytes and writeUTFBytes. but not working. also ExternalInterface don't allow passing arguments other than Object. is their any such problem ?

please help me how to transfer ByteArray between JS and AS3 (both direction)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ByteArray UTF functions are for dealing with UTF-encoded text.  Your sound data is not UTF encoded.  See below for an example of converting between an Object and a ByteArray in AS3...

```
// convert from a ByteArray to an Object:
ba.position = 0;
var obj:Object = ba.readObject();

// convert from Object to ByteArray:
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(obj);
```

However, I don't think it's true that ExternalInterface will only allow you to pass Objects.  If that's the case, then it's probably easiest to find a Base64 class (there are several available for AS3) and base64-encode your ByteArray before passing it to JS, and base64-decode it when receiving it.

Comment: thanks for you reply. the object conversion doesn't worked. But the hind Base64 really helped. its working now perfectly.